# Computer gives three beeps o starting and then no display

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Today I turned on my desktop, and it did not turn on. Nothing was displayed on the monitor and
then i heard my computer give out 1 long beep followed by two short beeps. The monitor then just remains blank.

What could be the problem?

I have an MSI X58 board with an Intel Core i7 950 CPU running Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: You didn't happen to change any hardware recently? (monitor, ram, etc..) From what I've been reading, it is video related (monitor / video card) Try changing monitors, and if that doesn't work, make sure your graphics card is properly seated and has all power cables running to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-long two-short beep code is usually graphics card related (it varies depending on bios however so check the beep codes for your bios).

The most likely reasons for this are:

1. Good: Your graphics card has vibrated out of its socket a bit, and needs to be reseated.
2. Bad: Your graphics card has failed and needs to be replaced

The former is just a case of opening the case and pushing it in (push in the memory and cpu while you are at it).  For the latter, if you have another card lying around, you could give that a go to confirm.

Comment: thank you. The graphics card connection was indeed loose. Had it toghtenede up and now it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Try bypassing graphics card by uninstalling then using onboard graphics, (that is if you have onboard.)